# Vertical expanding pop up window with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to find a way to enable my pop up window expand in a similar fashion as the Facebook Birthday popup expands. If you login to your Facebook page and click the "others" link next to where it shows how many of your friends have birthdays today, you will notice the pop up window shows up very small and then grows in a vertical fashion.

How am I able to do this?

I created a fiddle to show what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/05w8fpL5/

I have added..

```
.fadeIn("slow");
```

and

```
.fadeOut("slow");
```

So far which I like, but I wish I had some say so on how long it took to fadeIn and Out.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: _"had some say so on how long it took to fadeIn and Out."_ Tried setting `duration` of `.fadeIn(duration)` , `.fadeOut(duration)` to `.fadeIn(2000)` , `.fadeOut(2000)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`.slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) events in Jquery. This will provide the vertical expanding animation that you are looking for. So change your `.fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions, an **important note that the slide functions do not work with `min-height`**, you will need to remove that CSS from `.admin_help_popup` for this to work:

```
$('.admin_popup').on('click',function(){
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").slideDown("slow");
});

$('.close_admin_popup').on('click',function(){
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").slideUp("slow");
 });
```

If it's completely necessary you have that `min-height` property, you can set `min-height` back to it's default value after `.slideDown`. You can try and make it smoother by using `.animate()`. Make sure to set `mine-height` to `0px` on the slide up:

```
$('.admin_popup').on('click',function(){
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").slideDown("slow", function(){
        $(".admin_help_popup").animate({"min-height": "380px"}, "fast");
    });
});

$('.close_admin_popup').on('click',function(){
    $(".admin_help_popup").css("min-height", "0px");
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").slideUp("slow");
 });
```

[**Basic SlideUp/Down Fiddle Example without min-height**](https://jsfiddle.net/05w8fpL5/2/)

[**Fiddle example with min-height**](https://jsfiddle.net/05w8fpL5/3/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there anyway for it to appear as a box and then expand both at the top and bottom?